# Почему бот не отвечает на Inline кнопку?

Tags: python

После нажатия на кнопку "Перейти в меню" бот должен ответить пользователю, но этого не просиходит

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def work_bot(call):

    if call.data == 'q1':

        bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
        kn = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
        bt = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Перейти в меню',callback_data='q2')
        kn.add(bt)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='<b>Спасибо, что приняли наши правила!</b>', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=kn)
def next_step(call):

    if call.data == 'q2':

        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Меню')




if __name__=='__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: А что за библиотека?

Comment: pyTelegramBotAPI